# Drop down menu pushing content down

Tags: html, css, menu, dropdown

Good day, I made a blog on blogger and put some drop down menu codes from CSS-Tricks https://css-tricks.com/long-dropdowns-solution/. I tried changing the position and z-index codes but I can't make it stop pushing the content down. I've read the tutorials and applied the absolute, relative and fixed options for the position and even changing the z-index numbers, still can't find how to fix it. The dropdown works on the average menu but for the long one's it's messing with the photo.

This is my blog https://treeplantersph.blogspot.com/. The drop down menu is quite useful because it moves up and down without a scrollbar. Really helpful for viewers. Big big thanks for advice to solve my blog issue.

This is the codes I used:

```css
     <style type="text/css" style="display: none !important;">
        * {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
        body {
            overflow-x: hidden;
        }
        #demo-top-bar {
            text-align: left;
            background: #222;
            position: relative;
            zoom: 1;
            width: 100% !important;
            z-index:6000;
            padding: 20px 0 20px;
        }
        #demo-bar-inside {
            width: 960px;
            margin: 0 auto;
            position: relative;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
        #demo-bar-buttons {
            padding-top: 10px;
            float: right;
        }
        #demo-bar-buttons a {
            font-size: 12px;
            margin-left: 20px;
            color: white;
            margin: 2px 0;
            text-decoration: none;
            font: 14px "Lucida Grande", Sans-Serif !important;
        }
        #demo-bar-buttons a:hover,
        #demo-bar-buttons a:focus {
            text-decoration: underline;
        }
        #demo-bar-badge {
            display: inline-block;
            width: 302px;
            padding: 0 !important;
            margin: 0 !important;
            background-color: transparent !important;
        }
        #demo-bar-badge a {
            display: block;
            width: 100%;
            height: 38px;
            border-radius: 0;
            bottom: auto;
            margin: 0;
            background: url(/images/examples-logo.png) no-repeat;
            background-size: 100%;
            overflow: hidden;
            text-indent: -9999px;
        }
        #demo-bar-badge:before, #demo-bar-badge:after {
            display: none !important;
        }
    
    *                                     { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
    body                                { font: 15px Helvetica, Sans-Serif; } 
    html                                { overflow-y: scroll; }
    #page-wrap                            { width: 720px; margin: 25px auto; } 
    p                                   { margin: 0 0 8px 0; }
    a                                    { text-decoration: none; }
    img                                 { vertical-align: middle; }
    a img                               { border: 0; 180}
    ul                                    { list-style: none; }
    h1                                  { margin: 0 0 10px 0; }
    
    </style>
```

```html
  
    
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://css-tricks.com/examples/LongDropdowns/css/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen, projection"/>
    
        <script type='text/javascript' src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js?ver=1.3.2'></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://css-tricks.com/examples/LongDropdowns/js/jquery.dropdown.js"></script>    
    
    
        <div id="page-wrap">        
            <ul class="dropdown">
                <li><a href="#">Really Tall Menu<img src="https://css-tricks.com/examples/LongDropdowns/images/down-arrow.png" /></a>
                    <ul class="sub_menu">
                         <li><a href="#">Artificial Turf</a></li>
                         <li><a href="#">Benches &amp; Bleachers</a></li>
                         <li><a href="#">Communication Devices</a></li>
                         <li><a href="#">Dugouts</a></li>
                         <li><a href="#">Fencing &amp; Windscreen</a></li>
                         <li><a href="#">Floor Protectors</a></li>
                         <li><a href="#">Foul Poles</a></li>
                         <li><a href="#">Netting</a></li>
                         <li><a href="#">Outdoor Furniture &amp; Storage</a></li>
                         <li><a href="#">Outdoor Signs</a></li>
                         <li><a href="#">Padding</a></li>
                         <li><a href="#">Scoreboards</a></li>
                         <li><a href="#">Shade Structures</a></li>
                         <li><a href="#">Artificial Turf</a></li>
                         <li><a href="#">Benches &amp; Bleachers</a></li>
                         <li><a href="#">Communication Devices</a></li>
                         <li><a href="#">Dugouts</a></li>
                         <li><a href="#">Fencing &amp; Windscreen</a></li>
                         <li><a href="#">Floor Protectors</a></li>
                         <li><a href="#">Foul Poles</a></li>
                         <li><a href="#">Netting</a></li>
                         <li><a href="#">Outdoor Furniture &amp; Storage</a></li>
                         <li><a href="#">Outdoor Signs</a></li>
                         <li><a href="#">Padding</a></li>
                         <li><a href="#">Scoreboards</a></li>
                         <li><a href="#">Shade Structures</a></li>
                         <li><a href="#">Artificial Turf</a></li>
                         <li><a href="#">Benches &amp; Bleachers</a></li>
                         <li><a href="#">Communication Devices</a></li>
                         <li><a href="#">Dugouts</a></li>
                         <li><a href="#">Fencing &amp; Windscreen</a></li>
                         <li><a href="#">Floor Protectors</a></li>
                         <li><a href="#">Foul Poles</a></li>
                         <li><a href="#">Netting</a></li>
                         <li><a href="#">Outdoor Furniture &amp; Storage</a></li>
                         <li><a href="#">Outdoor Signs</a></li>
                         <li><a href="#">Padding</a></li>
                         <li><a href="#">Scoreboards</a></li>
                         <li><a href="#">Shade Structures</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Kinda Tall Menu</a>
                    <ul class="sub_menu">
                         <li><a href="#">Artificial Turf</a></li>
                         <li><a href="#">Benches &amp; Bleachers</a></li>
                         <li><a href="#">Communication Devices</a></li>
                         <li><a href="#">Dugouts</a></li>
                         <li><a href="#">Fencing &amp; Windscreen</a></li>
                         <li><a href="#">Floor Protectors</a></li>
                         <li><a href="#">Foul Poles</a></li>
                         <li><a href="#">Netting</a></li>
                         <li><a href="#">Outdoor Furniture &amp; Storage</a></li>
                         <li><a href="#">Outdoor Signs</a></li>
                         <li><a href="#">Padding</a></li>
                         <li><a href="#">Scoreboards</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Average Menu</a>
                    <ul class="sub_menu">
                         <li><a href="#">Artificial Turf</a></li>
                         <li><a href="#">Benches &amp; Bleachers</a></li>
                         <li><a href="#">Communication Devices</a></li>
                         <li><a href="#">Dugouts</a></li>
                         <li><a href="#">Fencing &amp; Windscreen</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">No Menu</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
    
        </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this CSS:

```
<style>
    ul.dropdown { z-index: 9; }
</style>
```